# Including opencv in a py2app-generated app

Tags: python, opencv, py2app

I'm using a mac with OS 10.7.2 and Apple's default python 2.7.1 installed. I installed opencv 2.3.1 via source and can confirm that `import cv` works from within python. I created a minimal python script (saved as "cvTest.py") that simply has `import cv` at the top and nothing else, then I used py2app (via terminal commands `py2applet --make-setup cvTest.py; python setup.py py2app`). When I move the resulting standalone app to a different computer (mac, OS 10.7.2) that doesn't have opencv installed and try to run the app it crashes, with the following error available via console.app:

```
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest: Traceback (most recent call last):
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:   File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 103, in <module>
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:     _argv_emulation()
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:   File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in _argv_emulation
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:     _get_argvemulator().mainloop()
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:   File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 40, in mainloop
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest:     stoptime = Evt.TickCount() + timeout
11-11-10 1:17:38.591 PM [0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TickCount'
11-11-10 1:17:38.661 PM cvTest: cvTest Error
11-11-10 1:17:39.888 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502: ([0x0-0xcb9cb9].org.pythonmac.unspecified.cvTest[49524]) Exited with code: 255
```

I then created a simple bash script that let me dig into the standalone app and run the app's binary from the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$0
PROGDIR=$(echo $CMD|perl -pe 's|/[^/]*$||')
cd "$PROGDIR"
"./cvTest.app/Contents/MacOS/cvTest"
```

Executing this yields the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 137, in <module>
    _run('cvTest.py')
  File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 134, in _run
    execfile(path, globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/ra/Downloads/cvTest.app/Contents/Resources/cvTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv
  File "cv.pyc", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
2011-11-10 13:18:26.239 cvTest[49578:707] cvTest Error

[Process completed]
```

So, what's going on here? Why am I getting an error, and is there any way to bundle opencv with a py2app-created app so that `import cv` works?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure.  But I'm working on an open source project that is computer vision based (It wrappers OpenCV) amongst others (http://www.simplecv.org).  One problem we are having is with deployment across platforms as we want 1-click installers.

We tried using Innosetup on windows and running into a lot of issues.  I got fed up so I started to write my own.  Basically what this program does is a bootstrap program.  You download our exe, run it, then it pulls in a list of files/libraries it needs and starts installing them.  So in our case we can install our software on a machine that has zero libraries installed.  The first thing it does it intall python, then setuptools, then opencv, etc.

Basically the app I'm releasing as open source is going to try and be a replacement for innosetup but cross platform.  If you want to see it as it stands now (about 85%) complete you can check it out at:
https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/installer/install/simplecv-installer.py

I plan to fork off this project when I'm done so it can be a universal installer that you just provide a manifest file to.
Here is the existing manifest:
https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/installer/install/manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that py2app builds a completely different Python distribution into the package. The distribution is supposed to be self-contained, so it needs to include all the libraries that the application may use at runtime (including OpenCV). Unfortunately, py2app seems to miss the required cv2.so file from dist/helloworld.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/ (see http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/implementation.html).

Here's what a working install of OpenCV looks like:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -1 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv*
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

So in theory, copying cv2.so to dist/helloworld.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.X/lib-dynload/ should solve the problem.

Unfortunately, it introduces another problem:

```
bash-3.2$ dist/main_wx.app/Contents/MacOS/main_wx 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

cv2.so has a ton of dependencies that need to be included:

```
bash-3.2$ otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so 
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so:
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.5)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I'm not sure how to handle them, but I have a feeling that without them, nothing is going to work. I'm leaving this here in hope someone else can use it to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finding and adding the dependencies to the py2app bundle can be done like this:

```
import os, sys, glob

frameworks = []
opencvLibs = glob.glob(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'lib', 'libopencv*.2.4.dylib'))
frameworks.extend(opencvLibs)

setup(app=['myApp'],
    options=dict(py2app=dict(
       frameworks=frameworks,
       includes = ['cv2',.....],
       packages = [........],
       ....
       )
    )
```

BUT unfortunately, that doesn't entirely solve the problem. For me it looks like cv2.so has been compiled with a static link to @rpath/Python but in your pyapp bundle it needs a relative link so that the app can move. :-(

Comment: That @rpath/Python reference can be fixed with `install_name_tool` – as long as the Python version you are bundling in the app is exactly the same as what's available in the path where that OpenCV library references it.